# render method warping sound; updated too frequently?

Tags: java, audio, libgdx, scene2d

I am using libGDX and aspects of scene2D.

I have a main Game class (code below). This main game class implements Screen and has a stage. 
I have two other classes (Dino and SpaceMonster), which extend Actor.

I want to be able to play a Sound once when there is an overlap between the Rectangle in the Dino class and the Rectangle in the SpaceMonster class.

**Problem**: no matter where I try and put the section of code that play's the Sound, it play's the sound many times over at insanely close intervals. I am quite sure this is because I have been putting the code (dealing with the overlap and corresponding sound) in methods that are updated many times a second.

**Question**: Can somebody explain to me where exactly I can put the section of code (dealing with the overlap and corresponding sound) where it will only play once, cleanly? Note that I have tried to put it in the Dino class, and the SpaceMonster class (on separate occasions), but I either hear nothing when the overlap occurs, or I get the same problem as above (where the sound is warped because it's playing many times a second), depending on what method I slot the code into.

Furthermore, if someone could explain to me where I should put game logic related code in general (in a location that's not constantly updated) when I use 'implements Screen', that'd be good. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding updates.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen
{ 
    private Stage stage;
    private Dino dino;
    private SpaceMonster spaceMonster;
    private Sound spacebarSound;

    public GameScreen(final ScreenManager gam) 
    {        
        this.game = gam;

        stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(800, 480));
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        dino = new Dino(); 
        spaceMonster = new SpaceMonster();

        stage.addActor(dino); 
        stage.addActor(spaceMonster);

        spacebarSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/spacebarSound.mp3"));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();   

        for (Rectangle spacebarRectangle : spacebar.getSpacebarRectangles())    // section of code
            if (spacebarRectangle.overlaps(dino.getDinoRectangle()))
                spacebarSound.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void show() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() 
    { 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sounds obviously repeats so often, because what you're doing in your renderloop at the moment is:

- check each rectangle
- if the rectangle overlaps with the dino, play the sound

Be aware, that everything you're doing in the renderloop usually happens about 60 times a second! That's really often if you think about how many times the sound will be started if each 60 frames rectangles overlap with the dino. Even if only one rectangle overlaps it'd happen 60 times a second.

---

My solution would be, to create a boolean value for example in your dino-class, that defines whether the dino is overlapping a rectangle or not. Instead of directly playing the sound when the rectangle overlaps with the dino, you could make something like that:

```
dino.setOverlapping(false);
for (Rectangle spacebarRectangle : spacebar.getSpacebarRectangles()) {   // section of code
        if (!dino.isOverlapping() && spacebarRectangle.overlaps(dino.getDinoRectangle())) {
            dino.setOverlapping(true);
            spacebarSound.play();
        }
}
```

so you'd only check if the dinosaur is overlapping if he already doesn't and you'd only play a sound when the boolean switched from false to true.

EDIT: after thinking a little bit more, an even better solution would be to skip the boolean thing and just do this:

```
for (Rectangle spacebarRectangle : spacebar.getSpacebarRectangles()) {   // section of code
        if (spacebarRectangle.overlaps(dino.getDinoRectangle())) {
            spacebarSound.play();
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed explanation. Unfortunately, the second chunk of code after the EDIT still produced the same result (the sound being played way too many times. Logically though, the break made sense and I thought it should work. I am yet to implement the first code chunk, and will give it a go when I get time. I understand more about the render loop now though.